# Escape Apostrophe in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, escaping

I am trying to escape an apostrophe in Selenium. Sample text below

```
<a title="My Day's Schedule"></a>
```

I am trying to search for this element using `//a[contains(@title , 'My Day's Schedule')]` , but this would not work since the apostrophe is not escaped. 
Tried various methods such as using the double quote to escape the apostrophe / using the java escape character ; but the XPath does not recognize the element

Any pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: Use a back slash \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a back-slash like `\` before the sign you want to escape.

If you sometimes don't want so escape to much you can also use part of the attributes like:
`//a[contains(@title, 's Schedule')]`

Or with escape:
`//a[@title='My Day\'s Schedule']`

As an alternative you can also use other attributes like `href` instead of `title`.

> Tip: use contains only when give part of the string, else use @attribute='string'

Comment: I tried using the backslash to escape the apostrophe ; but that does not seem to work. It is similar to the second option that you suggested ; not sure if I have to escape the single quotes at the beginning and end of the string also

My href has a different attribute ; so cannot base it on any other element

Comment: You only need to escape the ' from the middle, exactly as shown in the second option

Comment: The escaped XPath actually doesn't work. I just tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we use css here.?

Try to use the following which specify that the title of an anchor should ends with 'Schedule'

**CSS selector:**
    a[title$='Schedule']

Even if you want to go with xpath expression then please use the following

**xpath:**

- Method #1:

  By.xpath("//a[contains(@title, \"My Day's Schedule\")]")

or

- Method #2:

  By.xpath("//a[@title=\"My Day's Schedule\"]")

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it worked.

```
"//a[@title=\"My Day's Schedule\"]"
```